# Calculating which part of shift that falls within timespan

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, timespan

I am trying to make a formula to calculate how much of my shift that falls into another timespan (that gives extra shift hours)

I know how long my shift is, just need to have the red timespan in the picture.

E.g. I work between 15:00-23:00 and Timespan for extra payment is 19:00-24:00

The time I worked is 8 hours and 4 hours is extra pay, but is there any way to have a formula giving me this since I will have to do this for many dates and timespans...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have split your times (A start Shift, D end Extra Pay etc.) and times do not span midnight then:

```
=MIN(D1,B1)-MAX(C1,A1)
```

or `=B1-C1`.

Comment: Thanks, some times do span midnight, but at least this is a move in the right direction.